# Extracting (scraping) data from the web app which requires to log in [Node.js]

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am in position where I need to get some data from a page which does not provide any API.

**Situation is such**:

1. To get to the page data firstly you must log in (this normally
   creates some session storage / cookies in browser)
2. Then there get endpoint to get auth key (it checks if user is authenticated using the session storage / cookies which were created during login)
3. When you have auth key there are plenty of get endpoints which can be accessed   with it. That's what I need!

The actual login page is: https://w2.hronline.co.uk/account/login

Could I login just by creating https post to forms url when passing parameters with login credentials? If yes - would node create some session cookies / storage values, so later on I could make another get request to get auth key? If no, is there another way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't scrape directly in nodejs. You have to use some tools which provide you a web-browser in which you can execute js code/actions. Currenlty, I recommend you either Selenium, either PhantomJS.

PhantomJS is usable in nodejs, but it is limited since you can't use the require('') for all the nodejs libraries.

You can use some libraries which use PhantomJS and let you write the scraper in node.js. You should try first CasperJS which is made to do some unit tests like you want.

If you want to go further, you can try phantomjs-node which allows you to instanciate a phantomjs application in parallel, and to send it the js calls you need it to execute (requires to be used to phantomjs).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Strange that no one created something more light weight to do this task... I will have a play with CasperJs. (I will mark your answer as correct if there won't be any more better answers soon :))

Comment: @Tautvydas: some enterprises have theses tools, they earn their life with that and won't publish it.

Answer (score 0):

PhantomJS Is Dead, Use Chrome Headless [...] (https://semaphoreci.com/blog/2018/03/27/phantomjs-is-dead-use-chrome-headless-in-continuous-integration.html):

> In April 2017, Vitaliy Slobodin who was at the time the sole
> maintainer of PhantomJS, announced that he’s stepping down as
> maintainer, leaving the project effectively abandoned:
>
> > I think people will switch to it, eventually. Chrome is faster and
> > more stable than PhantomJS. And it doesn’t eat memory like crazy.

Since you're scraping, Chrome Headless is even more relevant than for CI/testing.
Chrome Headless is a real browser and behaves accordingly.
Here's how to do it:

- https://www.sitepoint.com/headless-chrome-node-js/
- https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-set-up-a-headless-chrome-node-js-server-in-docker/